# How to add 3 dataframes in a dataframe dict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 3 dataframes: `train`, `validation`, `test`.
I want to create a dictionary with these 3 dataframes to get the output below:

`features` are the dataframe columns's name

How ca I do this dictionary of dataframe?

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['ID', 'Tweet', 'anger', 'anticipation', 'disgust', 'fear', 'joy', 'love', 'optimism', 'pessimism', 'sadness', 'surprise', 'trust'],
        num_rows: 6838
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['ID', 'Tweet', 'anger', 'anticipation', 'disgust', 'fear', 'joy', 'love', 'optimism', 'pessimism', 'sadness', 'surprise', 'trust'],
        num_rows: 3259
    })
    validation: Dataset({
        features: ['ID', 'Tweet', 'anger', 'anticipation', 'disgust', 'fear', 'joy', 'love', 'optimism', 'pessimism', 'sadness', 'surprise', 'trust'],
        num_rows: 886
    })
})
```

I am trying this:

```
DatasetDict = {}

dataframes = [train, validation, test]
for grp in dataframes:
    
    DatasetDict[grp] = df
```

But it's not working

Comment: Is `DataSetDict` and `Dataset` a particular module/class, or just sudo-code? As is, your dictionary isn't valid...

Answer (score 0):

```
train.name = 'train'
test.name = 'test'
validation.name = 'validation'

datasetdict = {}
dataframes = [train, validation, test]
for df in dataframes:
    datasetdict[df.name] = {'features': df.columns.to_list(), 'num_rows': len(df)}
```